# Why does the Ajax form on error return both a message and a form?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

The first attempts to create something on Ajax. There is a form in which you need to enter a name. If you enter more than 3 (restriction as in the example), you receive an error message + the same form. Total error message and two identical forms. Full despair comes. Please tell me how to fix it? Thank you in advance! I apologize for the translation.

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
       public ActionResult Name(Name name)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.SaveName(name);

                if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                {
                    return PartialView("NameSent");
                }
                return View("NameSent");
            }
                return View();
            }
```

**View Name**

```
@{
    AjaxOptions ajaxName = new AjaxOptions
    {
        UpdateTargetId = "target",
        HttpMethod = "post"        
    };
}
<div>
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <p id="target"></p>
</div>

<div class="">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Name", ajaxName))
    {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
        <div class="">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

**Model**

```
public class Name
    {
        public int NameId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Your name")]
        [StringLength(3)] /*For example*/
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

That's what I see.

[image]

Comment: Because your `Ajax.BeginForm()` calls a method which returns a partial view and inserts into the element with `<p id="target"></p>` If you want to replace the current form, then the `<p>` element should wrap your `Ajax.BeginForm()` code

Comment: Thanks for the answer. And how to do it? How do I make the <p> element close my form?

Comment: `<p id="target">@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Name", ajaxName)){ ..... }</p>` (and your `@Html.ValidationSummary()` needs to be inside the form)

Comment: There is a property on Ajax.BeginForm method which allows you to specify that whatever response is returned should Replace the existing HTML with what's returned from the call.  I think that is what you are looking for.  Check out the documentation; it's an enum value.

Comment: Did as you said. The result is the same. I make an error + the second form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** I expanded the code sample below to show more clearly what I mean

Because on error, you're returning the standard view for the form:

```
return View();
```

You'd need to branch as you do above when the model is valid:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Name(Name name)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveName(name);

        if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            return PartialView("NameSent");
        }
        return View("NameSent");
    }

    if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        return PartialView("NameError");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Also, FWIW, when the model is valid and the request isn't AJAX, you should redirect, rather than returning a view. That's part of the well-known PRG (Post-Redirect-Get) pattern. By redirecting, you prevent the user accidentally resubmitting by refreshing.

Comment: Can you tell me how to do it right? If I change the NameSent to NameError
I completely stop receiving messages about the successful execution that is stored in NameSent

Comment: No, you misunderstand. I meant you do need to do the same specific return when called via AJAX on failure as you do when the model is valid. See the expanded code sample above.

Comment: Error CS0428 The "IsAjaxRequest" method group could not be converted to a type that is not the current "bool". Was it supposed to write this method out?
Not quite clear! Even if it works .. how can I explain that if the form is successfully executed, the form remains (it is not cleared) and simply outputs the message (from above or below)? Why does the form remain anyway? How can I clean it if I succeed?

Comment: Sorry. I forgot the parenthesis on `IsAjaxRequest`.

Comment: To some extent, it became easier. The error shows. Thank you very much!!!
I understood to what result you aspired.
Can I ask another question?
1. And if there are several fields ... let's say two, name and surname, he already can not specify in which error exactly because in this case @ Html.ValidationSummary () does not work anymore?
2. The form still remains, but at least not two. And is there any method that will do a) On success - the message replaces the form and b) If the failure to highlight the fields.
Once again, thank you very much!